# Redirect when session expires

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, spring-security

I have used one of the several approaches for solving issue with redirecting to login page when ajax or non-ajax event occurred and session was expired: https://gist.github.com/banterCZ/5160269

During testing ajax case in debug mode, I have performed following steps:

1. Open two tabs in my browser.
2. Perform login.
3. The first page is displayed data table with several action buttons.
4. The second page is displayed log out button.
5. So, when I press log out button, I am going into the JsfRedirectStrategy class into else statement:

Bean:

```
@Component 
public class JsfRedirectStrategy implements InvalidSessionStrategy {

    final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JsfRedirectStrategy.class);

    private static final String FACES_REQUEST_HEADER = "faces-request";

    private String invalidSessionUrl = "/login.xhtml";

    @Override
    public void onInvalidSessionDetected(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        boolean ajaxRedirect = "partial/ajax".equals(request.getHeader(FACES_REQUEST_HEADER));
        if (ajaxRedirect) {
            String contextPath = request.getContextPath();
            String redirectUrl = contextPath + invalidSessionUrl;
            logger.debug("Session expired due to ajax request, redirecting to '{}'", redirectUrl);

            String ajaxRedirectXml = createAjaxRedirectXml(redirectUrl);
            logger.debug("Ajax partial response to redirect: {}", ajaxRedirectXml);

            response.setContentType("text/xml");
            response.getWriter().write(ajaxRedirectXml);
        } else { 
            String requestURI = getRequestUrl(request);
            logger.info(
                    "Session expired due to non-ajax request, starting a new session and redirect to requested url '{}'",
                    requestURI);
            request.getSession(true);
            response.sendRedirect(requestURI);
        }

    }

    private String getRequestUrl(HttpServletRequest request) {
        StringBuffer requestURL = request.getRequestURL();

        String queryString = request.getQueryString();
        if (StringUtils.hasText(queryString)) {
            requestURL.append("?").append(queryString);
        }

        return requestURL.toString();
    }

    private String createAjaxRedirectXml(String redirectUrl) {
        return new StringBuilder().append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>")
                .append("<partial-response><redirect url=\"")
                .append(redirectUrl)
                .append("\"></redirect></partial-response>").toString();
    }
}
```

and the following message is printed: 
**Session expired due to non-ajax request, starting a new session and redirect to requested url**

So, **new session** was opened, even user was logged out.

**6.** Then I am going to the first page and press one of the action button to trigger ajax event, but nothing happened (no action.)

the following message is printed:
**o.s.b.a.audit.listener.AuditListener - AuditEvent [timestamp=Tue Nov 03 17:44:39 EET 2015, principal=anonymousUser, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE, data={type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException, message=Access is denied}]**

I suppose that reason of such behavior is executing this sample of code at **step 5**:

```
request.getSession(true);
```

From my point of view, the correct behavior would be if result of **step 6** would be redirecting to the **loging** page.

**So, please tell me how to achieve this?**

My Spring Security config is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off   
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/invite.xhtml").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login.xhtml").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/forgotpassword.xhtml").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/resetpwd.xhtml").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/admin/*").hasRole(Roles.ROLE_ADMIN.getSpringSecName())
            .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/actuator/*").permitAll()
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login.xhtml").permitAll()
                    //.failureUrl("/login?error").permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher( new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login.xhtml")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new AjaxAwareAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login.xhtml"));

        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();

        http.addFilterBefore(sessionManagementFilter(), FilterSecurityInterceptor.class);
     // @formatter:on
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/javax.faces.resource/**");
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository httpSessionSecurityContextRepository() {
        return new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository();
    }

    @Bean
    public JsfRedirectStrategy jsfRedirectStrategy() {
        return new JsfRedirectStrategy();
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionManagementFilter sessionManagementFilter() {
        SessionManagementFilter sessionManagementFilter = new SessionManagementFilter(
                httpSessionSecurityContextRepository());
        sessionManagementFilter.setInvalidSessionStrategy(jsfRedirectStrategy());
        return sessionManagementFilter;
    }

}
```

Comment: How is this PrimeFaces related? Does it work with plain jsf components ?

Comment: Yes, I am using  different <p: components from primefaces library, e.g: DataTable, commandButton etc...

Comment: So if it works plain JSF components but not with PrimeFaces components, why don't you post your xhtml. One with working and one with none-working tags/components? And just the fact that you use PrimeFaces components does not mean a thing. You use energy too and most likely that is based on fossil fuel, so you use charcoal or oil and burning that requires oxygen, but you did not add those tags either ;-). So please edit your question and make it right.

Comment: I have found solution for my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33516570/5284890

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSF PrimeFaces ajax request after logout and session invalidation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33503794/jsf-primefaces-ajax-request-after-logout-and-session-invalidation)